# How to fix signout button doesnt recognize (click) in html file

Tags: angular

I setted a Signout button which should take user back to signin screen 
but the problem is that the button doesn't do anything and my guess is `(click)="onLoggedOut($event)"` can't be recognized.

`topnav.component.html`:
https://ibb.co/sw3cJZG

This is the site status when I press the button: 
https://ibb.co/jDcRKyB

### Code of `topnav.component.ts` :

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
        import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
        import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-topnav',
          templateUrl: './topnav.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./topnav.component.css']
        })
        export class TopnavComponent implements OnInit {

          @Input()
          userEmail: string;

          @Input()
          isloggedIn: boolean;

          constructor(
            private as: AuthService,
            private router: Router
          ) { }

          ngOnInit() {
          }

          onLoggedOut(event) {
            event.preventDefaut();
            this.isloggedIn = false;
            this.as.logout();
            window.location.reload();
          }

        }
```

`logout()` function:

```
logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();

  }
```

Comment: What's the reason for event.preventDefault();

Comment: I even deleted the function the real problem is that the function cant recognized in html file

Comment: did you try alert in onLoggedOut function?

Comment: huh I tried and the onLoggedOut function started. so , the problem is in my code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.reload();` is reloading the entire applications, if you have any async functions in your service they are probably not going to run.

Never reload in angular unless you want to restart the application.

Try this:

```
         onLoggedOut(event) {
            event.preventDefaut();
            this.isloggedIn = false;
            this.as.logout();
            this.router.navigate(['/some/path']);
          }
```

*I do not know everything going in here, but that stood out as a problem.*